# How can I make an object accessible from all the methods of the page but in a way that the content of its properties are unique for each user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I make an object of a custom class, accessible from all the methods of the page (default.cs) but in a way that the content of the properties inside the object are unique for each user that uses the app simultaneously?

I have the following code:

```
namespace LawfirmsRewiever
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class CLASSBenefitIncluded326
        {
            public string Begin { get; set; }
            public string End326 { get; set; }
            public string LOB { get; set; }

            public int id326 { get; set; }
          

            public CLASSBenefitIncluded326()
            {
                this.Begin = null;
                this.End326 = null;
                this.LOB = null;
                this.id326 = 0;
           
            } 
            
            public CLASSBenefitIncluded326(string f, string l, string u, int a, string g, string j, string h, string Benefit326, string Medios326, string PrimerPago326)
            {
                this.Begin = f;
                this.End326 = l;
                this.LOB = u;
                this.id326 = a;

            }
        }

public static CLASSBenefitIncluded326 Lawfirm1= new CLASSBenefitIncluded326();
public static CLASSBenefitIncluded326 Lawfirm2= new CLASSBenefitIncluded326();
```

As I said, the content of the strings inside the objects (Lawfirm1 and Lawfirm2) should be managed separately and individually in memory, in a way that if User A and User B are using the app at the same time, do not share the content of the such variables. How can I do it easily?

Comment: Not really following what you’re doing here. But if you want the instances to be per-user, they can’t be static

Comment: you are creating new instances of the class so for each user they will get their own.

Comment: I can confirm that using static, all users share the same instance. Which alternative i have to not use static, but with access to the instance in all methods?

Comment: You need a data repository with a collection of the objects and some way to link the right object to the user. I suggest you read up on databases, ORMs and data serialization.